# RequestStreamHandler AWS Lambda - how to trigger from port 5000 in AWS?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a low-level lambda that, currently, is just an echo server to verify feasibility.

Now, I'm stuck around the 'triggers' to use.  When using API gateways, they expect JSON content, which I want to allow anything and have the RequestStreamHandler take care of the parsing/protocol piece.

Also, want to allow 'any' defined port, so HTTP, raw TCP, whatever.

Question: How to configure AWS to support an external call to a random port (5000) that could be 'any content' and have the RequestStreamHandler AWS Lambda parse and respond back (i.e. what trigger would call the Lambda for essentially raw (synchronous) TCP requests)?

Thanks!
-D